# Are there conflicts using ROS Fuerte Gazebo and DRC Gazebo Simulator on the same ubuntu precise computer?

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have Ubuntu Precise and ROS Fuerte with Gazebo 1.6.16 on my computer.
I'd like to install the Darpa Grand Challenge Simulator (DRC simulator) on the same computer.

Will the DRC simulator have conflicts with the ROS-based Gazebo simulator?

I don't want to corrupt my current ROS-based Gazebo.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/889/are-there-conflicts-using-ros-fuerte-gazebo-and-drc-gazebo-simulator-on-the-same-ubuntu--precise-computer?/) by [samq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/157/samq/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You shouldn't have conflicts between the two installations of Gazebo.  The ROS Fuerte software is installed in `/opt/ros/fuerte/`.  The gazebo and drcsim packages that OSRF provides will install into `/usr/`.

If you do notice conflicts, please file a ticket so that we can look into it.  And you can always just uninstall the `gazebo` package to get back to your current state.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1